# What adhesive is typically used to "glue" a porcelain under-counter sink to a stone countertop

Tags: kitchen-sink, remodeling, vanity, granite

Is it silicone adhesive that kitchen and bathroom remodelers use to "glue" a porcelain sink to the underside of a granite countertop around the perimeter of the cutout?  Something else?

P.S. I know there's also a kind of screw attachment; I'm interested in the chemical composition of the substance since I want to detach the sink from the countertop.

Comment: I don't know enough to write an answer, but I believe if clips cannot be used, a special two-part epoxy is used to suspend the sink and then it's finished with silicone for a seal.  I believe construction adhesive or silicone adhesive are used to add strength to mechanical mounts when heavy sinks are mounted to  stone countertops with clips.

Comment: @jay613 To a point, but for the largest part used to seal the sink against the countertop. The "glue" part is a handy side-effect I think.

Comment: You can get "silicone sealant remover" it it turns out to be that. Can you see any of it squished out from the inside?

Comment: Where are you? I suspect this is a regional thing, as my experience in California is exclusively with 2 part epoxy -- never just silicone. (Though silicone always follows in the crack.) One last question: are you trying to preserve the sink you're removing? Life would be easier and more smashtastic if you didn't need to save the sink.

Comment: @AndrewMorton  no squishing; it was a pretty neat job.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate :  Philadelphia metro.  Definitely trying to preserve the sink. I want to flip it around. At present vanity faucet is wall-mount and I want to install counter-top faucet instead, but the "fat" side of the countertop is oriented towards the front, so the countertop needs to be rotated.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely it's silicone. You should be able to cut it with a razor/knife to free the sink and then scrape/peel it off completely once the sink is out of the way.

Comment: Silicone is used because it also happens to make a nice water tight barrier to the water that _will_ try to work its way between the bowl and countertop.

Comment: It'll get in there somewhere!

Comment: @FreeMan - that's *all* it's for. Other than it'd get gross.

Comment: @gnicko - agreed. And it is always fail so never fill up your sink to the countertop.

Answer (score 4):

You can get silicones that are also adhesives. Best of both worlds.
Just search "silicone adhesive".

[A selection from a UK builders' merchant chain.](https://www.screwfix.com/c/sealants-adhesives/hybrid-sealants-adhesives/cat12310001)

Comment: Does this mean we can dispense with L-brackets or all-round strapping, which usually function as primary support for the sink?

Comment: @P2000 you could risk it, I would not.

Comment: Or....are they adhesives...that are also silicone?

Comment: @SolarMike indeed I wouldn't. That begs the question, then why use silicone *adhesive* at all?

Comment: Don't. That's not what hangs a sink with 100 lbs of water in it. That's what keeps it from leaking.

Comment: @P2000 two comments have told you that: hold it in place and stop leaks.  Water will find its wsy through gaps. If you don’t read the comments then us trying to help…

Comment: @SolarMike No, I am not asking "why silicone", I am asking why "silicone *adhesive*" (as I emphasized in my comment) once you've decided for brackets anyway. As they say, if you don’t read the comments ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever it is it's softer than both granite and porcelain

Just use a wire to cut through it.

Comment: Is there a kind of thin abrasive wire that works like a saw blade? Or just any thin wire?  I would like to preserve the sink, BTW.

Comment: Any thin high tensile strength wire.  spring steel works well.

Comment: “Pvc pipe cable saw” would be your best bet. (Even Home Depot carries a few.) But I’m not convinced that it’ll work well if you’re up against epoxy.